# CSV to JSON promesa

Tags: javascript, json, array, csv, promesas

Teniendo este código:

```
const Converter = require("csvtojson");
const ReadLine = require("readline-sync");
const fs = require("fs");

//Variable que guarda los datos para poder operar con ellos más tarde.
var products = [];
//let result;
//let pricesObj;

//PREGUNTA POR LOS ARCHIVOS
let csvFile = ReadLine.questionPath("Set CSV File name: "); //pregunta por el archivo CSV.
//let jsonFile = ReadLine.questionPath("Set JSON File name: "); //pregunta por el archivo JSON.

//ESTO LEE EL CSV
Converter({delimiter: ";"}).fromFile(csvFile).then(source => {
    for (let index = 0; index < source.length; index++) {
        products.push(source[index])
    }
    console.log(products);
});

//PARA LEER EL JSON
/*let readFile = fs.readFileSync(jsonFile);
pricesObj = JSON.parse(readFile);*/

console.log("Fuera: " + products);
console.log(typeof(products))
//console.log(pricesObj);
```

Al ejecutar en consola me devuelve lo siguiente:
   [image: Resultado]

Entiendo que tendrá que ver con la sincronía de la devolución de los datos, pero no soy capaz de ponerle solución.
Me gustaría que me echárais un cable con ello.

Lo que pretendo es sacar el resultado del "Converter" en una variable externa para poder operar con ella junto con el JSON que también se lee (aunque está comentado en este momento).

Answer (score 0):

No hay un afuera cuando la llamada es asíncrona, para mantener lo mas parecido a lo que quieres puedes poner todo dentro de una función `async`:

```
const Converter = require("csvtojson");
const ReadLine = require("readline-sync");
const fs = require("fs");

(async () => {

    let csvFile = ReadLine.questionPath("Set CSV File name: "); //pregunta por el archivo CSV.

    const products = await Converter({ delimiter: ";" }).fromFile(csvFile);

    console.log(products);


})();
```

Además, no necesitas hacer un push de cada valor, porque ya retorna un array.